# Why does SFAuthenticationSession prompt for consent every time?

Tags: ios, oauth, sfauthenticationsession

I'm using `SFAuthenticationSession` with **SSO** and **OAuth**.

When calling the `start()` method, iOS pops up a consent dialog asking the user to allow the app to use the **OAuth** provider. The consent popup appears every time the authentication session is started.

Is this by design? It seems like it should appear once, like other consent dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design yes. There is really nothing you can do to avoid the consent dialog as of now when using `SFAuthenticationSession`, it's working as Apple wanted it to work. Check out Apple's own documentation on `SFAuthenticationSession` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession)

Comment: It is possible to customise such dialog?

Comment: Unfortunately not.